# Form dropdown selection

Tags: html, forms, select

I have an HTML form with a dropdown list of addresses. My client needs the selected address to appear large at the bottom of the form data so that the recipient can print the email containing the form data and cut the large address off the bottom of the sheet to be used as a shipping label.

Comment: Please provide more detail, including sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Inline scripts is not the best and most flexible practice. I would go with a solution more like this.
http://jsbin.com/mewunu/1/edit?html,js,output

When the menu option is selected, you need to place the value of that selected option in your shipping label area.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However the address didn't appear large at the bottom in my form email, see below: 
realname: 
First_Name: TEST
Last_Name: TEST
Company_Name: EnerCare Solutions
Shipping_Address: 2525 Victoria Park Avenue, Toronto, ON M2H 3P4
Mens_Size: ...
Womens_Size: 2X
Color: Black
Qty: 1
Submit: Submit

Comment: To change the appearance, you will need some CSS. Please edit the jsbin page to post your own html, js and css.

Answer (score 1):

This is my form code right now:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Company Name
- EnerCare Solutions
  Shipping Address
- ...
              80 Allstate Parkway, Markham, ON, L3R 6H3
              30 High Meadow, Toronto, ON, M6L 2Z5
              4000 Victoria Park Avenue, Toronto, ON M2H 3P4

- Mens Size
            Womens Size
- ...
              Small
              Medium
              Large
              XL
              XXL
              3X
              4X
              5X
      
              
                ...
                X-Small
                Small
                Medium
                Large
                XL
                2X
                3X
- 
- 

  Color
            Black
  Qty  
              1

This is what my recipient's email looks like:
email: 
realname: 
First_Name: TEST
Last_Name: TEST
Company_Name: Enercare Solutions
Shipping_Address: 4000 Victoria Park Avenue, Toronto, ON M2H 3P4
Mens_Size: ...
Womens_Size: 2X
Color: Black
Qty: 1
Submit: Submit

I NEED THE SELECTED SHIPPING ADDRESS TO APPEAR HERE in 36pt TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<select id="select" onchange='document.getElementById("large").innerHTML = document.getElementById("select").value'>
    <option>Select address...</option>
    <option>Address 1</option>
    <option>Address 2</option>
</select>
<h2 id="large"></h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6x0mv9qe/

Just check if the select is changed and add it's value to the element you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However the address didn't appear large at the bottom in my form email, see below: realname: First_Name: TEST Last_Name: TEST Company_Name: EnerCare Solutions Shipping_Address: 2525 Victoria Park Avenue, Toronto, ON M2H 3P4 Mens_Size: ... Womens_Size: 2X Color: Black Qty: 1 Submit: Submit

Comment: Tried this using a text area named large in place of h2, because h2 didn't show up in the email. Data went to the text area on select and was submitted successfully however the shipping address did not appear large in the email submission. Is there any way to format the email before it goes to the recipient?

Comment: Sure, you can set the font-size using css, most email-clients should be able to display this:
<textarea style="font-size: 30"></textarea>